# Como alterar div 3 imagens em linha para apenas 2 imagens em linha para modo tablet

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5

Boa tarde, 
Sou iniciante na parte de Html,CSS e Javascript e este é o meu primeiro projeto. 
Eu e o meu grupo estamos a fazer um site cujo tema é sobre parques temáticos.
Quase no fundo da página, tenho 3 imagens em cada linha, quando o site está no modo web, tal como mostra a seguinte imagem.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
 Quando é para telemóvel (até 470px), Todas as imagens umas por baixo das outras.
A minha dúvida está quando a vista é para tablets (mais ou menos até 850px), tenho cada div com 3 imagens, e gostaria que a página fosse apresentada com 3 linhas de imagens, cada linha com apenas 2 imagens. Ou seja, ficasse como mostro na foto seguinte. Mas não sei como fazer essa parte pois estão 3 imagens em cada div

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Junto coloco o meu código HTML e CSS desta página

```js
// --------------------------------------------IMAGEM 1----------------------------------------------------
var slideIndex1 = 1;
showDivs1(slideIndex1);

function plusDivs1(n) {
  showDivs1(slideIndex1 += n);
}

function showDivs1(n) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("imagem1");
  if (n > x.length) {slideIndex1 = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex1 = x.length}
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
     x[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  x[slideIndex1-1].style.display = "block";  
}
// --------------------------------------------IMAGEM 2----------------------------------------------------
var slideIndex2 = 1;
showDivs2(slideIndex2);
function plusDivs2(n) {
  showDivs2(slideIndex2 += n);
}

function showDivs2(n) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("imagem2");
  if (n > x.length) {slideIndex2 = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex2 = x.length}
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
     x[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  x[slideIndex2-1].style.display = "block";  
}
// --------------------------------------------IMAGEM 3----------------------------------------------------
var slideIndex3 = 1;
showDivs3(slideIndex3);
function plusDivs3(n) {
  showDivs3(slideIndex3 += n);
}

function showDivs3(n) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("imagem3");
  if (n > x.length) {slideIndex3 = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex3 = x.length}
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
     x[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  x[slideIndex3-1].style.display = "block";  
}
// --------------------------------------------IMAGEM 4----------------------------------------------------
var slideIndex4 = 1;
showDivs4(slideIndex4);
function plusDivs4(n) {
  showDivs4(slideIndex4 += n);
}

function showDivs4(n) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("imagem4");
  if (n > x.length) {slideIndex4 = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex4 = x.length}
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
     x[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  x[slideIndex4-1].style.display = "block";  
}
// --------------------------------------------IMAGEM 5----------------------------------------------------
var slideIndex5 = 1;
showDivs5(slideIndex5);
function plusDivs5(n) {
  showDivs5(slideIndex5 += n);
}

function showDivs5(n) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("imagem5");
  if (n > x.length) {slideIndex5 = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex5 = x.length}
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
     x[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  x[slideIndex5-1].style.display = "block";  
}
// --------------------------------------------IMAGEM 6----------------------------------------------------
var slideIndex6 = 1;
showDivs6(slideIndex6);
function plusDivs6(n) {
  showDivs6(slideIndex6 += n);
}

function showDivs6(n) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("imagem6");
  if (n > x.length) {slideIndex6 = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex6 = x.length}
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
     x[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  x[slideIndex6-1].style.display = "block";  
}
```

```css
*{margin: 0; padding: 0;}  /* Coloca as margens e padding do navegador a 0*/

body{
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:16px;
}

/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*                                        CORPO PÁG                                            */
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/ 
.texto{ /* Texto inicial antes de todas as diversões */
    margin-top: 2%;
    margin-bottom: 2%;
    font-family: Cambria, Cochin, Georgia, Times, 'Times New Roman', serif;
    font-size: 20px;
}
h1{
    color:red;
}

#div_titulo_parque{
    background-color: white;    
    padding-top: 10px;
}
#titulo_parque{
    font-size: 72px; 
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Cambria, Cochin, Georgia, Times, 'Times New Roman', serif;

    /*TÍTULO COM GRADIENTE*/
 background: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(255, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(214, 105, 105, 0.753) 75%);
 -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;

}

.Titulo_Diversoes{
   color: rgba(248, 41, 41, 0.842);
}
.p_textodiversao{ /* Texto de cada diversão*/
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-top: 16px;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
}

.Diversao{
    margin-bottom: 3%;
}

.Video_Diversao{  /* vídeo de cada diversão*/
    /* position: relative;  */
    float: right;
    margin-right: 7px;
    
}
#fundo_texto{
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 7px;
}


#imagem_centro{
    width:100%;
    height: 400px;
}

.texto_imagem{
    margin-top: -30px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 8, 0, 0.575); /* rgba -> a -> opacidade -> 0-muito 1-nada*/
    width: 100%;
 
}

h3{
    color: white;
    margin-left: 7px;
}

.imagem_outras_atracoes{
    width:100%; 
    height:270px;

}   

.imagem_e_texto_outras_atracoes{
    position: relative;
    width: 27%;
    height: auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.outras_atracoes{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    place-content: space-between;
    margin-bottom: 3%;
}

.seta_dir{
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 130px;
    margin-left: 87%;
    width: 7%;
}
.seta_esq{
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 130px;
    margin-left: 5%;
    width: 7%;
}

.mySlides {
    display:none;
}

button{
    width: 5%;
    height: 23px;
}
.botao_esquerda{
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 130px;
}
.botao_direira{
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 130px;
    margin-left: 95%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 470px)
{
    #imagem_centro{
        width:100%;
        height: 250px;
    }

    .Video_Diversao{  /* vídeo de cada diversão*/
        /* position: relative;  */
        float:none;
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        display: block;
        
    }
    
    .imagem_outras_atracoes{
        width:100%; 
        height:270px;

    }   

    .imagem_e_texto_outras_atracoes{
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        margin-bottom: 30px;
    }

    .outras_atracoes{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        place-content: space-between;
        margin-bottom: 3%;
    }
    .Titulo_Diversoes{
        color: rgba(248, 41, 41, 0.842);
        margin-bottom: 15px;
     }

}

/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title>Ferrari Park</title>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../menu/menu.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../menu/projeto.css">
            <script src="../menu/react.js"></script>
            <script src="../menu/react-dom.js"></script>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style_FerrariPark.css">
    </head>
    <body>   
        <div id="data-hora"></div> <!-- div que vai mostrar a data e hora -->
    
    <!-- ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
    <header> <!-- Inserir o Cabeçalho -->
        <div id="menudiv"></div> <!-- div para o menu -->
        </header>
     <!-- ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
    
     <div id="div_titulo_parque"><h1 id="titulo_parque">Ferrari PARK</h1></div>
        <!-- Esta div contém a imagem do parque temático  -->
    <div > 
        <img id="imagem_centro" src="../imagens/ferraripark.jpg">
    </div>
        
    <!-- ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
    <div id="fundo_texto">
        <!-- video de apresentação do parque temático -->
        <div class="texto">
            <p>FerrariPark é um dos nossos principais parques temáticos e é ideal para quem gosta de corridas e adrenalina.</p>
            <p>Tem diversas diversões focadas em velcidade e para amantes de F1.</p>
            <p>Vem e diverte-te!!!</p>
        </div>
        <h1>Principais Atrações</h1><br>
        <div class="Diversao">
            <h2 class="Titulo_Diversoes">Red Force</h2>
            <iframe class="Video_Diversao" width="300" height="170" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/VzvqtT4hga0" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer;encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            <p class="p_textodiversao">Desfruta de uma viagem sensasional cheia de adrenalina com um percurso de 880 metros, atingindo 180km/h com uma altura máxima de 112metros.</p>
            <p class="p_textodiversao">O Red Force usa energia eletromagnética, fornecida por motores síncronos lineares, para lançar seus carros dos 0 aos 180 Km/h em apenas cinco segundos, e a seguir escala uma torre em forma de cartola com ângulo vertical de 90 graus  </p>
            <p class="p_textodiversao">Esta diversão é mais direcionada para adultos e crianças com idade superior a 14 anos. </p>
            <!-- <p class="p_textodiversao">Desfruta de uma viagem sensasional cheia de adrenalina com um percurso de 880 metros, atingindo 180km/h e uma altura máxima de 112metros </p> -->
        </div>
    
        <div class="Diversao">
            <h2 class="Titulo_Diversoes">Torre de Emoções</h2>
            <iframe class="Video_Diversao" width="300" height="200" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/mGqZbVAOSDE" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            <p class="p_textodiversao">Sente a adrenalina e o movimento dos pistões de um motor Ferrari enquanto és lançado em direção ao céu e depois em direção ao chão</p>
            <p class="p_textodiversao">Esta diversão possui um motor de 600 Cv V12, equiparado ao um motor de fórmula 1. Vem experimentar e sente a adrenalina de andar num carro de F1. </p>
            <p class="p_textodiversao">Entra nesta diversão que te vai proporcionar muita adrenalina e emoção.</p>
            <p class="p_textodiversao">Sente a adrenalina e o movimento dos pistões de um motor Ferrari enquanto és lançado em direção ao céu e depois em direção ao chão</p>
        </div>
    
        <div class="Diversao">
            <h2 class="Titulo_Diversoes">Flying Aces</h2>
            <iframe  class="Video_Diversao" width="300" height="200" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/4dq6oxI8Hy0" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            <p class="p_textodiversao">Suba a bordo do seu biplano militar e escala 63 metros em uma inclinação espetacular de 51 graus. Sinta sua pulsação enquanto voa pelo circuito mais alto da montanha-russa do mundo e atinge velocidades de até 120 km / h.</p>
            <p class="p_textodiversao">Inspirado pelo lendário aviador do ás de ases, o Conde Baracca. Escale 63m em uma inclinação espetacular de 51 graus, alcance 120 km / h e voe pelo circuito mais alto da montanha-russa do mundo.</p>
            <p class="p_textodiversao">Esta diversão possui um motor de 600 Cv V12, equiparado ao um motor de fórmula 1. Vem experimentar e sente a adrenalina de andar num carro de F1. </p>
            <p class="p_textodiversao">Sente a adrenalina e o movimento dos pistões de um motor Ferrari enquanto és lançado em direção ao céu e depois em direção ao chão</p>
        </div>

        <h1>Outras atrações</h1><br>

        <!-- --------------------------------------------IMAGEM 1 ---------------------------------------------------->
        <div class="outras_atracoes">
            <div class="imagem_e_texto_outras_atracoes">
                <!-- <img src="../imagens/seta_direita.png" class="seta_dir" onclick="mudarfoto_frente_1_1();">
                <img src="../imagens/seta_esquerda.png" class="seta_esq" onclick="mudarfoto_tras_1_1();"> -->
                <img class="imagem_outras_atracoes imagem1" src="../imagens/fp1_1.jpg">
                <img class="imagem_outras_atracoes imagem1" src="../imagens/fp1_2.jfif">
                <img class="imagem_outras_atracoes imagem1" src="../imagens/fp1_3.jpg">
                <button class="botao_esquerda" onclick="plusDivs1(-1)">&#10094;</button><!-- &#10094 unicode para seta da esquerda-->
                <button class="botao_direira" onclick="plusDivs1(1)">&#10095;</button><!-- &#10095 unicode para seta da direira-->
                <div class="texto_imagem">
                    <h3 class="nome_atracao">Racing legends</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        <!-- --------------------------------------------IMAGEM 2 ---------------------------------------------------->
        <div class="imagem_e_texto_outras_atracoes">
                <img class="imagem_outras_atracoes imagem2" src="../imagens/fp2_1.jpg">
                <img class="imagem_outras_atracoes imagem2" src="../imagens/fp2_2.jpg">
                <img class="imagem_outras_atracoes imagem2" src="../imagens/fp2_3.jpg">
                <img class="imagem_outras_atracoes imagem2" src="../imagens/fp2_4.webp">
                <button class="botao_esquerda" onclick="plusDivs2(-1)">&#10094;</button><!-- &#10094 unicode para seta da esquerda-->
                <button class="botao_direira" onclick="plusDivs2(1)">&#10095;</button><!-- &#10095 unicode para seta da direira-->
                <div class="texto_imagem">
                    <h3 class="nome_atracao">Formula Rossa</h3>
                    <!-- Fazer setas para mudar de imagem, ver exercício 2 ficha 7 -->
                </div>
            </div>
        <!-- --------------------------------------------IMAGEM 3 ---------------------------------------------------->
        <div class="imagem_e_texto_outras_atracoes">
            <img class="imagem_outras_atracoes imagem3" src="../imagens/fp3_2.jpg">
            <img class="imagem_outras_atracoes imagem3" src="../imagens/fp3_1.jpg">
            <img class="imagem_outras_atracoes imagem3" src="../imagens/fp3_3.jpg">
            <img class="imagem_outras_atracoes imagem3" src="../imagens/fp3_4.jpg">
            <img class="imagem_outras_atracoes imagem3" src="../imagens/fp3_5.jpg">
            <button class="botao_esquerda" onclick="plusDivs3(-1)">&#10094;</button><!-- &#10094 unicode para seta da esquerda-->
            <button class="botao_direira" onclick="plusDivs3(1)">&#10095;</button><!-- &#10095 unicode para seta da direira-->
            <div class="texto_imagem">
                <h3 class="nome_atracao">Junior Grand Prix</h3> 
                <!-- Fazer setas para mudar de imagem, ver exercício 2 ficha 7 -->
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="outras_atracoes">
        <!-- --------------------------------------------IMAGEM 4 ---------------------------------------------------->
            <div class="imagem_e_texto_outras_atracoes">
                <img class="imagem_outras_atracoes imagem4" src="../imagens/fp4_1.jpg">
                <img class="imagem_outras_atracoes imagem4" src="../imagens/fp4_2.jpg">
                <img class="imagem_outras_atracoes imagem4" src="../imagens/fp4_3.jpg">
                <img class="imagem_outras_atracoes imagem4" src="../imagens/fp4_4.jpg">
                <button class="botao_esquerda" onclick="plusDivs4(-1)">&#10094;</button><!-- &#10094 unicode para seta da esquerda-->
                <button class="botao_direira" onclick="plusDivs4(1)">&#10095;</button><!-- &#10095 unicode para seta da direira-->
                <div class="texto_imagem">
                    <h3 class="nome_atracao">Scuderia Challenge</h3>
                    <!-- Fazer setas para mudar de imagem, ver exercício 2 ficha 7 -->
                </div>
            </div>
        <!-- --------------------------------------------IMAGEM 5 ---------------------------------------------------->
            <div class="imagem_e_texto_outras_atracoes">
                <img class="imagem_outras_atracoes imagem5" src="../imagens/fp5_1.jpg">
                <img class="imagem_outras_atracoes imagem5" src="../imagens/fp5_3.jpg">
                <button class="botao_esquerda" onclick="plusDivs5(-1)">&#10094;</button><!-- &#10094 unicode para seta da esquerda-->
                <button class="botao_direira" onclick="plusDivs5(1)">&#10095;</button><!-- &#10095 unicode para seta da direira-->
                <div class="texto_imagem">
                    <h3 class="nome_atracao">Karting Academy</h3>
                    <!-- Fazer setas para mudar de imagem, ver exercício 2 ficha 7 -->
                </div>
            </div>
        <!-- --------------------------------------------IMAGEM 6 ---------------------------------------------------->

        <div class="imagem_e_texto_outras_atracoes">
            <img class="imagem_outras_atracoes imagem6" src="../imagens/fp6_1.jpg">
            <img class="imagem_outras_atracoes imagem6" src="../imagens/fp6_2.jpg">
            <img class="imagem_outras_atracoes imagem6" src="../imagens/fp6_.jpg">
            <button class="botao_esquerda" onclick="plusDivs6(-1)">&#10094;</button><!-- &#10094 unicode para seta da esquerda-->
            <button class="botao_direira" onclick="plusDivs6(1)">&#10095;</button><!-- &#10095 unicode para seta da direira-->
            <div class="texto_imagem">
                <h3 class="nome_atracao">CRAZY PISTONS</h3>                    
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
    <script src="../menu/menu.js"></script> <!-- script do menu -->
    <script src="script_FerrariPark.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Agradecia imenso se algúem me conseguisse ajudar.

Feliz natal e próspero Ano Novo a todos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aqui vai uma solução, não separe 3 imagens por row (linha), deixei todas as imagens dentro de um *container* só, e vai mudando a largura das imagens nos *breacking points*, tipo, quando for até 870px as imagens devem ter 47% de largura, assim caberão apenas 2 por linha. Para isso é preciso que vc coloque `flex-wrap: wrap` no container da imagens

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Segue o código da imagem acima:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title>Ferrari Park</title>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../menu/menu.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../menu/projeto.css">
            <script src="../menu/react.js"></script>
            <script src="../menu/react-dom.js"></script>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style_FerrariPark.css">
            <style>
            *{margin: 0; padding: 0;}  /* Coloca as margens e padding do navegador a 0*/

body{
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:16px;
}

/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*                                        CORPO PÁG                                            */
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/ 
.texto{ /* Texto inicial antes de todas as diversões */
    margin-top: 2%;
    margin-bottom: 2%;
    font-family: Cambria, Cochin, Georgia, Times, 'Times New Roman', serif;
    font-size: 20px;
}
h1{
    color:red;
}

#div_titulo_parque{
    background-color: white;    
    padding-top: 10px;
}
#titulo_parque{
    font-size: 72px; 
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Cambria, Cochin, Georgia, Times, 'Times New Roman', serif;

    /*TÍTULO COM GRADIENTE*/
 background: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(255, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(214, 105, 105, 0.753) 75%);
 -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;

}

.Titulo_Diversoes{
   color: rgba(248, 41, 41, 0.842);
}
.p_textodiversao{ /* Texto de cada diversão*/
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-top: 16px;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
}

.Diversao{
    margin-bottom: 3%;
}

.Video_Diversao{  /* vídeo de cada diversão*/
    /* position: relative;  */
    float: right;
    margin-right: 7px;
    
}
#fundo_texto{
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 7px;
}


#imagem_centro{
    width:100%;
    height: 400px;
}

.texto_imagem{
    margin-top: -30px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 8, 0, 0.575); /* rgba -> a -> opacidade -> 0-muito 1-nada*/
    width: 100%;
 
}

h3{
    color: white;
    margin-left: 7px;
}

.imagem_outras_atracoes{
    width:100%; 
    height:270px;

}   

.imagem_e_texto_outras_atracoes{
    position: relative;
    width: 27%;
    height: auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;

    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.outras_atracoes{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    place-content: space-between;
    margin-bottom: 3%;

    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.seta_dir{
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 130px;
    margin-left: 87%;
    width: 7%;
}
.seta_esq{
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 130px;
    margin-left: 5%;
    width: 7%;
}

.mySlides {
    display:none;
}

button{
    width: 5%;
    height: 23px;
}
.botao_esquerda{
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 130px;
}
.botao_direira{
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 130px;
    margin-left: 95%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 870px)
{
  .imagem_e_texto_outras_atracoes {
    position: relative;
    width: 47%;
    height: auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 470px)
{
    #imagem_centro{
        width:100%;
        height: 250px;
    }

    .Video_Diversao{  /* vídeo de cada diversão*/
        /* position: relative;  */
        float:none;
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        display: block;
        
    }
    
    .imagem_outras_atracoes{
        width:100%; 
        height:270px;

    }   

    .imagem_e_texto_outras_atracoes{
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        margin-bottom: 30px;
    }

    .outras_atracoes{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        place-content: space-between;
        margin-bottom: 3%;
    }
    .Titulo_Diversoes{
        color: rgba(248, 41, 41, 0.842);
        margin-bottom: 15px;
     }

}

            </style>
    </head>
    <body>   
        <div id="data-hora"></div> <!-- div que vai mostrar a data e hora -->
    
    <!-- ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
    <header> <!-- Inserir o Cabeçalho -->
        <div id="menudiv"></div> <!-- div para o menu -->
        </header>
     <!-- ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
    
     <div id="div_titulo_parque"><h1 id="titulo_parque">Ferrari PARK</h1></div>
        <!-- Esta div contém a imagem do parque temático  -->
    <div > 
        <img id="imagem_centro" src="../imagens/ferraripark.jpg">
    </div>
        
    <!-- ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
    <div id="fundo_texto">
        <!-- video de apresentação do parque temático -->
        <div class="texto">
            <p>FerrariPark é um dos nossos principais parques temáticos e é ideal para quem gosta de corridas e adrenalina.</p>
            <p>Tem diversas diversões focadas em velcidade e para amantes de F1.</p>
            <p>Vem e diverte-te!!!</p>
        </div>
        <h1>Principais Atrações</h1><br>
        <div class="Diversao">
            <h2 class="Titulo_Diversoes">Red Force</h2>
            <iframe class="Video_Diversao" width="300" height="170" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/VzvqtT4hga0" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer;encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            <p class="p_textodiversao">Desfruta de uma viagem sensasional cheia de adrenalina com um percurso de 880 metros, atingindo 180km/h com uma altura máxima de 112metros.</p>
            <p class="p_textodiversao">O Red Force usa energia eletromagnética, fornecida por motores síncronos lineares, para lançar seus carros dos 0 aos 180 Km/h em apenas cinco segundos, e a seguir escala uma torre em forma de cartola com ângulo vertical de 90 graus  </p>
            <p class="p_textodiversao">Esta diversão é mais direcionada para adultos e crianças com idade superior a 14 anos. </p>
            <!-- <p class="p_textodiversao">Desfruta de uma viagem sensasional cheia de adrenalina com um percurso de 880 metros, atingindo 180km/h e uma altura máxima de 112metros </p> -->
        </div>
    
        <div class="Diversao">
            <h2 class="Titulo_Diversoes">Torre de Emoções</h2>
            <iframe class="Video_Diversao" width="300" height="200" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/mGqZbVAOSDE" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            <p class="p_textodiversao">Sente a adrenalina e o movimento dos pistões de um motor Ferrari enquanto és lançado em direção ao céu e depois em direção ao chão</p>
            <p class="p_textodiversao">Esta diversão possui um motor de 600 Cv V12, equiparado ao um motor de fórmula 1. Vem experimentar e sente a adrenalina de andar num carro de F1. </p>
            <p class="p_textodiversao">Entra nesta diversão que te vai proporcionar muita adrenalina e emoção.</p>
            <p class="p_textodiversao">Sente a adrenalina e o movimento dos pistões de um motor Ferrari enquanto és lançado em direção ao céu e depois em direção ao chão</p>
        </div>
    
        <div class="Diversao">
            <h2 class="Titulo_Diversoes">Flying Aces</h2>
            <iframe  class="Video_Diversao" width="300" height="200" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/4dq6oxI8Hy0" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            <p class="p_textodiversao">Suba a bordo do seu biplano militar e escala 63 metros em uma inclinação espetacular de 51 graus. Sinta sua pulsação enquanto voa pelo circuito mais alto da montanha-russa do mundo e atinge velocidades de até 120 km / h.</p>
            <p class="p_textodiversao">Inspirado pelo lendário aviador do ás de ases, o Conde Baracca. Escale 63m em uma inclinação espetacular de 51 graus, alcance 120 km / h e voe pelo circuito mais alto da montanha-russa do mundo.</p>
            <p class="p_textodiversao">Esta diversão possui um motor de 600 Cv V12, equiparado ao um motor de fórmula 1. Vem experimentar e sente a adrenalina de andar num carro de F1. </p>
            <p class="p_textodiversao">Sente a adrenalina e o movimento dos pistões de um motor Ferrari enquanto és lançado em direção ao céu e depois em direção ao chão</p>
        </div>

        <h1>Outras atrações</h1><br>

        <!-- --------------------------------------------IMAGEM 1 ---------------------------------------------------->
        <div class="outras_atracoes">
            <div class="imagem_e_texto_outras_atracoes">
                <!-- <img src="../imagens/seta_direita.png" class="seta_dir" onclick="mudarfoto_frente_1_1();">
                <img src="../imagens/seta_esquerda.png" class="seta_esq" onclick="mudarfoto_tras_1_1();"> -->
                <img class="imagem_outras_atracoes imagem1" src="../imagens/fp1_1.jpg">
                <img class="imagem_outras_atracoes imagem1" src="../imagens/fp1_2.jfif">
                <img class="imagem_outras_atracoes imagem1" src="../imagens/fp1_3.jpg">
                <button class="botao_esquerda" onclick="plusDivs1(-1)">&#10094;</button><!-- &#10094 unicode para seta da esquerda-->
                <button class="botao_direira" onclick="plusDivs1(1)">&#10095;</button><!-- &#10095 unicode para seta da direira-->
                <div class="texto_imagem">
                    <h3 class="nome_atracao">Racing legends</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        <!-- --------------------------------------------IMAGEM 2 ---------------------------------------------------->
        <div class="imagem_e_texto_outras_atracoes">
                <img class="imagem_outras_atracoes imagem2" src="../imagens/fp2_1.jpg">
                <img class="imagem_outras_atracoes imagem2" src="../imagens/fp2_2.jpg">
                <img class="imagem_outras_atracoes imagem2" src="../imagens/fp2_3.jpg">
                <img class="imagem_outras_atracoes imagem2" src="../imagens/fp2_4.webp">
                <button class="botao_esquerda" onclick="plusDivs2(-1)">&#10094;</button><!-- &#10094 unicode para seta da esquerda-->
                <button class="botao_direira" onclick="plusDivs2(1)">&#10095;</button><!-- &#10095 unicode para seta da direira-->
                <div class="texto_imagem">
                    <h3 class="nome_atracao">Formula Rossa</h3>
                    <!-- Fazer setas para mudar de imagem, ver exercício 2 ficha 7 -->
                </div>
            </div>
        <!-- --------------------------------------------IMAGEM 3 ---------------------------------------------------->
        <div class="imagem_e_texto_outras_atracoes">
            <img class="imagem_outras_atracoes imagem3" src="../imagens/fp3_2.jpg">
            <img class="imagem_outras_atracoes imagem3" src="../imagens/fp3_1.jpg">
            <img class="imagem_outras_atracoes imagem3" src="../imagens/fp3_3.jpg">
            <img class="imagem_outras_atracoes imagem3" src="../imagens/fp3_4.jpg">
            <img class="imagem_outras_atracoes imagem3" src="../imagens/fp3_5.jpg">
            <button class="botao_esquerda" onclick="plusDivs3(-1)">&#10094;</button><!-- &#10094 unicode para seta da esquerda-->
            <button class="botao_direira" onclick="plusDivs3(1)">&#10095;</button><!-- &#10095 unicode para seta da direira-->
            <div class="texto_imagem">
                <h3 class="nome_atracao">Junior Grand Prix</h3> 
                <!-- Fazer setas para mudar de imagem, ver exercício 2 ficha 7 -->
            </div>
            </div>
 
        <!-- --------------------------------------------IMAGEM 4 ---------------------------------------------------->
            <div class="imagem_e_texto_outras_atracoes">
                <img class="imagem_outras_atracoes imagem4" src="../imagens/fp4_1.jpg">
                <img class="imagem_outras_atracoes imagem4" src="../imagens/fp4_2.jpg">
                <img class="imagem_outras_atracoes imagem4" src="../imagens/fp4_3.jpg">
                <img class="imagem_outras_atracoes imagem4" src="../imagens/fp4_4.jpg">
                <button class="botao_esquerda" onclick="plusDivs4(-1)">&#10094;</button><!-- &#10094 unicode para seta da esquerda-->
                <button class="botao_direira" onclick="plusDivs4(1)">&#10095;</button><!-- &#10095 unicode para seta da direira-->
                <div class="texto_imagem">
                    <h3 class="nome_atracao">Scuderia Challenge</h3>
                    <!-- Fazer setas para mudar de imagem, ver exercício 2 ficha 7 -->
                </div>
            </div>
        <!-- --------------------------------------------IMAGEM 5 ---------------------------------------------------->
            <div class="imagem_e_texto_outras_atracoes">
                <img class="imagem_outras_atracoes imagem5" src="../imagens/fp5_1.jpg">
                <img class="imagem_outras_atracoes imagem5" src="../imagens/fp5_3.jpg">
                <button class="botao_esquerda" onclick="plusDivs5(-1)">&#10094;</button><!-- &#10094 unicode para seta da esquerda-->
                <button class="botao_direira" onclick="plusDivs5(1)">&#10095;</button><!-- &#10095 unicode para seta da direira-->
                <div class="texto_imagem">
                    <h3 class="nome_atracao">Karting Academy</h3>
                    <!-- Fazer setas para mudar de imagem, ver exercício 2 ficha 7 -->
                </div>
            </div>
        <!-- --------------------------------------------IMAGEM 6 ---------------------------------------------------->

        <div class="imagem_e_texto_outras_atracoes">
            <img class="imagem_outras_atracoes imagem6" src="../imagens/fp6_1.jpg">
            <img class="imagem_outras_atracoes imagem6" src="../imagens/fp6_2.jpg">
            <img class="imagem_outras_atracoes imagem6" src="../imagens/fp6_.jpg">
            <button class="botao_esquerda" onclick="plusDivs6(-1)">&#10094;</button><!-- &#10094 unicode para seta da esquerda-->
            <button class="botao_direira" onclick="plusDivs6(1)">&#10095;</button><!-- &#10095 unicode para seta da direira-->
            <div class="texto_imagem">
                <h3 class="nome_atracao">CRAZY PISTONS</h3>                    
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
    <script src="../menu/menu.js"></script> <!-- script do menu -->
    <script src="script_FerrariPark.js"></script>
    <script>
    // --------------------------------------------IMAGEM 1----------------------------------------------------
var slideIndex1 = 1;
showDivs1(slideIndex1);

function plusDivs1(n) {
  showDivs1(slideIndex1 += n);
}

function showDivs1(n) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("imagem1");
  if (n > x.length) {slideIndex1 = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex1 = x.length}
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
     x[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  x[slideIndex1-1].style.display = "block";  
}
// --------------------------------------------IMAGEM 2----------------------------------------------------
var slideIndex2 = 1;
showDivs2(slideIndex2);
function plusDivs2(n) {
  showDivs2(slideIndex2 += n);
}

function showDivs2(n) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("imagem2");
  if (n > x.length) {slideIndex2 = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex2 = x.length}
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
     x[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  x[slideIndex2-1].style.display = "block";  
}
// --------------------------------------------IMAGEM 3----------------------------------------------------
var slideIndex3 = 1;
showDivs3(slideIndex3);
function plusDivs3(n) {
  showDivs3(slideIndex3 += n);
}

function showDivs3(n) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("imagem3");
  if (n > x.length) {slideIndex3 = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex3 = x.length}
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
     x[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  x[slideIndex3-1].style.display = "block";  
}
// --------------------------------------------IMAGEM 4----------------------------------------------------
var slideIndex4 = 1;
showDivs4(slideIndex4);
function plusDivs4(n) {
  showDivs4(slideIndex4 += n);
}

function showDivs4(n) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("imagem4");
  if (n > x.length) {slideIndex4 = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex4 = x.length}
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
     x[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  x[slideIndex4-1].style.display = "block";  
}
// --------------------------------------------IMAGEM 5----------------------------------------------------
var slideIndex5 = 1;
showDivs5(slideIndex5);
function plusDivs5(n) {
  showDivs5(slideIndex5 += n);
}

function showDivs5(n) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("imagem5");
  if (n > x.length) {slideIndex5 = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex5 = x.length}
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
     x[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  x[slideIndex5-1].style.display = "block";  
}
// --------------------------------------------IMAGEM 6----------------------------------------------------
var slideIndex6 = 1;
showDivs6(slideIndex6);
function plusDivs6(n) {
  showDivs6(slideIndex6 += n);
}

function showDivs6(n) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("imagem6");
  if (n > x.length) {slideIndex6 = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex6 = x.length}
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
     x[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  x[slideIndex6-1].style.display = "block";  
}

/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda. Feliz natal!

Comment: @GonçaloCosta para vc tb meu amigo, feliz natal!

Answer (score 1):

Você pode colocar todas as divs dentro de uma só, em vez de dividir. Por exemplo, você coloca todas as divs `.imagem_e_texto_outras_atracoes` dentro de uma só div `.outras_atracoes`.

Nas divs `.imagem_e_texto_outras_atracoes` você troca o `width: 27%` por `flex-basis: 27%;`, que define a largura inicial das divs, e acrescente uma margem inferior com `margin-bottom: 3%;`. Ficará assim:

```
.imagem_e_texto_outras_atracoes{
    position: relative;
    height: auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-basis: 27%;
    margin-bottom: 3%;
}
```

Na div principal `.outras_atracoes` você coloca `flex-wrap: wrap;`, para que as divs filhas mudem de linha automaticamente se não couberem na largura. Ficará assim:

```
.outras_atracoes{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    place-content: space-between;
    margin-bottom: 3%;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

E para finalizar, acrescente no seu CSS um breakpoint para as larguras até `850px` alterando o `flex-basis` das divs para ficarem apenas 2 por linha:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 850px)
{
 .imagem_e_texto_outras_atracoes{
    flex-basis: 45%;
}
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda. Feliz natal!